# What is the FileInputStream on Netty

Tags: java, netty

I Want to know what is the FileInputStream on Netty because i need to use it on Files!
Need help on this!
Thanks,
Migue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer files use the DefaultFileRegion.

```
Channel channel =...
channel.write(new DefaultFileRegion(new FileInputStream(file).getChannel(), 0L, file.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** `FileInputStream` is used when you want to **read** a `File` in form of **bytes**, or reading a **byte array** etc.....

Comment: Yes i want to read a file,but i think netty do it with more perfomance or not?

Comment: Netty does that in java too. You will not get extra performance if you reads a file in java. They are all calling standard java IO/NIO apis.